# Cannot execute command from docker run using jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:4.3-1

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

### Problem

I'm using the Docker image [jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:4.3-1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jenkinsci/jnlp-slave/4.3-1/images/sha256-eab945da86d8b3245c7682dc88383ecc6a2e75b2a7c02c31f3cb205e076c008e?context=explore).

I tried to execute commands from the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) like this:

```
docker run --rm jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:4.3-1 cat /etc/os-release
```

However, it seems the command is not executed in a usual way.
For example, the above command resulted in an error:

```
$docker run --rm jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:4.3-1 cat /etc/os-release
At least one -url option is required.
java -jar agent.jar [options...] <secret key> <agent name>
 -agentLog FILE                        : Local agent error log destination
                                         (overrides workDir)
 -cert VAL                             : Specify additional X.509 encoded PEM
                                         certificates to trust when connecting
                                         to Jenkins root URLs. If starting with
                                         @ then the remainder is assumed to be
                                         the name of the certificate file to
                                         read.
 -credentials USER:PASSWORD            : HTTP BASIC AUTH header to pass in for
                                         making HTTP requests.
 -direct (-directConnection) HOST:PORT : Connect directly to this TCP agent
                                         port, skipping the HTTP(S) connection
                                         parameter download. For example,
                                         "myjenkins:50000".
 -disableHttpsCertValidation           : Ignore SSL validation errors - use as
                                         a last resort only. (default: false)
 -failIfWorkDirIsMissing               : Fails the initialization if the
                                         requested workDir or internalDir are
                                         missing ('false' by default) (default:
                                         false)
 -headless                             : Run agent in headless mode, without
                                         GUI (default: false)
 -help                                 : Show this help message (default: false)
 -instanceIdentity VAL                 : The base64 encoded InstanceIdentity
                                         byte array of the Jenkins master. When
                                         this is set, the agent skips
                                         connecting to an HTTP(S) port for
                                         connection info.
 -internalDir VAL                      : Specifies a name of the internal files
                                         within a working directory ('remoting'
                                         by default) (default: remoting)
 -jar-cache DIR                        : Cache directory that stores jar files
                                         sent from the master
 -loggingConfig FILE                   : Path to the property file with
                                         java.util.logging settings
 -noKeepAlive                          : Disable TCP socket keep alive on
                                         connection to the master. (default:
                                         false)
 -noreconnect                          : If the connection ends, don't retry
                                         and just exit. (default: false)
 -protocols VAL                        : Specify the remoting protocols to
                                         attempt when instanceIdentity is
                                         provided.
 -proxyCredentials USER:PASSWORD       : HTTP BASIC AUTH header to pass in for
                                         making HTTP authenticated proxy
                                         requests.
 -tunnel HOST:PORT                     : Connect to the specified host and
                                         port, instead of connecting directly
                                         to Jenkins. Useful when connection to
                                         Jenkins needs to be tunneled. Can be
                                         also HOST: or :PORT, in which case the
                                         missing portion will be auto-configured
                                         like the default behavior
 -url URL                              : Specify the Jenkins root URLs to
                                         connect to.
 -version                              : Shows the version of the remoting jar
                                         and then exits (default: false)
 -webSocket                            : Make a WebSocket connection to Jenkins
                                         rather than using the TCP port.
                                         (default: false)
 -workDir FILE                         : Declares the working directory of the
                                         remoting instance (stores cache and
                                         logs by default)
```

### Expected Behavior

I tried the same using a different image such as [ubuntu:21.04](https://hub.docker.com/layers/ubuntu/library/ubuntu/21.04/images/sha256-6f3e7192e61cbb6a29b1af7b33385faaa695e6120b46b2a9065e827717b3dc9b?context=explore).

The command was executed in a normal way like this:

```
$docker run --rm ubuntu:21.04 cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (development branch)"
VERSION_ID="21.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hirsute
UBUNTU_CODENAME=hirsute
```

### Question

1. I wonder why a simple Linux command generates different results depending on the image.
   The command `cat /etc/os-release` worked fine when it was executed in a different way like this:

   ```
   $docker run --rm -it jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:4.3-1 /bin/bash
   jenkins@4a7d91e19e3a:~$ cat /etc/os-release
   PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
   NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
   VERSION_ID="10"
   VERSION="10 (buster)"
   VERSION_CODENAME=buster
   ID=debian
   HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
   SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
   BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
   ```
2. Is it possible to execute commands from the `docker run` using `jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:4.3-1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every image has an `ENTRYPOINT`. This is an executable object (with optional arguments) that is called when you start a container. You can use `docker inspect` to find the default entrypoint value. Here's the entrypoint for the `docker.io/jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:4.3-1` image:

```json
"Entrypoint": [
  "jenkins-agent"
],
```

and this one is for ubuntu:

```
"Entrypoint": null,
```

When you run jenkins image with `cat /etc/os-release` command, you effectively execute this command:

```
jenkins-agent cat /etc/os-release
```

When you do that in ubuntu, it is `null + cat /etc/os-release`, that is just `cat /etc/os-release`. And that is why the error is happening.

It is possible to override the default entrypoint at runtime, for that use `--entrypoint=<value>` option. For example, to run `cat /etc/os-release` in jenkins image you may try this:

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint="" jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:4.3-1 cat /etc/os-release
```

Also be ready to accept that some images have nothing inside except one binary file of the application. In such images you will not find `sh`, `ls`, `cat`, etc.